# Advanced indexing alternative for njit numba function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Given the following minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# variable number of dimensions
n_t = 8
# q is just a partition of n
q_ddl = 2
n_ddl = 3

np.random.seed(42)
df = np.random.rand(q_ddl*n_t,q_ddl*n_t)

# index array
# ddl_nl is a set of np.arange(n_ddl), ex: [0,1] ; [0,2] or even [0] ...
ddl_nl = np.array([0,1])
ij = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(ddl_nl,ddl_nl,indexing='ij'))

@jit(nopython=True)
def foo(df,ij):
    out = np.zeros((n_t,n_ddl,n_ddl))
    for i in range(0,n_t):     
        d_i = np.zeros((n_ddl,n_ddl))
        # (q_ddl,q_ddl) non zero values into (n_ddl,n_ddl) shape
        d_i[ij[0], ij[1]] = df[i::n_t,i::n_t]
        # to check possible solutions
        out[i,...] = d_i
    return out


out_foo = foo(df,ij)
```

The function `foo` is working well when `@jit(nopython=True)` is disabled but it is throwing the following error when enabled:

```
TypeError: unsupported array index type array(int64, 2d, C) in UniTuple(array(int64, 2d, C) x 2)
```

which happened during the broadcasting operation `d_i[ij[0], ij[1]] = df[i::n_t,i::n_t]`. Then, I did try to flatten the 2d index arrays `ij` with something like `d_i[ij[0].ravel(), ij[1].ravel()] = df[i::n_t,i::n_t].ravel()` which gives me the same output but now another error:

```
NotImplementedError: only one advanced index supported
```

So I finally tried to dodge this by using a classical 2 nested `for` loops structure:

```
tmp = df[i::n_t,i::n_t]
for k,r in enumerate(ddl_nl):
    for l,c in enumerate(ddl_nl):
        d_i[r,c] = tmp[k,l]
```

which is working with the decorator enabled and gives the intended result.

But I can't stop thinking if there is any numba-compatible alternatives for this numpy 2d-array broadcasting operation that I am missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define "numba friendly" :)

Comment: Is the meshgrid also in your real function? Is the Number of dimensions always the same? You don't need things like meshgrid or fancy indexing at all for this example. Even if it would work it would be slower than simple nested loops. Using gloabls like n_t is also really not recommendable (you can't change them without recompilation)

Comment: Number of dimensions is not always the same... But q is only a partition of n. By numba-friendly, I meant numba compatible. You 2 are right, thanks for these answers, for loops are just  as fast (even quicker) as fancy approach in this case, I ll think I go this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking some of your values:

```
In [446]: ddl_nl = np.array([0,1]) 
     ...: ij = np.asarray(np.meshgrid(ddl_nl,ddl_nl,indexing='ij')) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [447]: ij                                                                                   
Out[447]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
In [448]: n_t = 8 
     ...: q_ddl = 2 
     ...: n_ddl = 3                                                                            
In [449]: d_i = np.zeros((n_ddl,n_ddl))                                                        
In [450]: d_i                                                                                  
Out[450]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
In [451]: d_i[ij[0], ij[1]]                                                                    
Out[451]: 
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

try a more diagnositic `d_i`:

```
In [452]: d_i = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                                                      
In [453]: d_i[ij[0], ij[1]]                                                                    
Out[453]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
In [454]: d_i[:2,:2]                                                                           
Out[454]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])
```

Why are you using advanced indexing when a basic slicing would work?

I haven't tried this with `numba`, but it may have a better chance of working.  That said, the enumerated loop might be just as fast.  I don't have enough experience with `numba` to say for sure.

===

Clearly you have hit a `numpy` operation that `numba` does not support:

```
In [456]: numba.__version__                                                                    
Out[456]: '0.43.0'
In [457]: @numba.jit 
     ...: def foo(arr): 
     ...:     return arr[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [458]: foo(np.eye(4))                                                                       
Out[458]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [459]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo(arr): 
     ...:     return arr[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [460]: foo(np.eye(4))    
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 2d, C), tuple(list(int64) x 2))
```

That's not unusual.  `numba` does not claim to have full coverage of `Python` or `numpy`.

But with `numba` we don't have to avoid iteration.  In fact it's at its best when replacing an operation that `numpy` can't do without iteration.

```
In [465]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo(arr): 
     ...:     out = np.zeros((3,), arr.dtype) 
     ...:     for n, (i,j) in enumerate(zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3])): 
     ...:         out[n] = arr[i,j] 
     ...:     return out 

In [466]: foo(np.eye(4))                                                                       
Out[466]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [467]: timeit foo(np.eye(4))                                                                
6.85 µs ± 28.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [468]: np.eye(4)[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]                                                           
Out[468]: array([1., 1., 1.])
In [469]: timeit np.eye(4)[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]                                                    
13.3 µs ± 31.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Avoid fancy indexing

Also avoid using global variables (they are hardcoded at compile time) and keep your code as simple as possible (simple means only a dew loops, if/else,...). If the `ddl_nl` array is really only constructed using np.arange, even this array isn't needed at all.

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def foo_nb(df,n_ddl,n_t,ddl_nl):
    out = np.zeros((n_t,n_ddl,n_ddl))
    for i in range(0,n_t):
        for ii in range(ddl_nl.shape[0]):
            ind_1=ddl_nl[ii]
            for jj in range(ddl_nl.shape[0]):
                ind_2=ddl_nl[jj]
                out[i,ind_1,ind_2] = df[i+ii*n_t,i+jj*n_t]
    return out
```

**Timings**

```
#Testing and compilation
A=foo(df,ij)
B=foo_nb(df,n_ddl,n_t,ddl_nl)
print(np.allclose(A,B))
#True
%timeit foo(df,ij)
#16.8 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit foo_nb(df,n_ddl,n_t,ddl_nl)
#674 ns ± 2.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```